# In Perl, what is the efficient way to replace a String dynamically with something else?

Tags: string, perl, replace

I have a file containing many lines like

```
"resourcename" : "myfile.pdf",
```

I want to replace everywhere myfile.pdf with an URL like `http://somedomain.com/myfile.pdf`. But the file name keeps changing. So if myfile.pdf becomes yourfile.pdf, I want to replace it with `http://somedomain.com/yourfile.pdf`.

What is an efficient way to do global replacement(`/g`) without affecting the file's encoding like UTF-8?

Thanks

Comment: perl shouldn't change the encoding..

Comment: what do you mean 'like UTF-8'?  is the encoding UTF-8? or sometimes different things?  if the latter, what are the different possibilities?

Comment: Sorry, I mentioned UTF-8 because when I updated it with Java and it looks like it changes the encoding somehow.  If perl does not change it, then it is great.

Comment: can you give out an sample of regex in this case? Still not sure about its usage.

Comment: "regex" is improper terminology on user3033490's part. use the substition operator.  how depends on what exactly you mean in your question; some sample input and output would really help.  (I don't know from what you say if you mean sometimes myfile should be replace by yourfile, or different runs of the program might change different fixed filenames, or just any filename ending pdf should be changed to a link or any filename whatever the ending.)